# Creating an Array of String[] from Notes Multivalue fileds

Tags: java, arrays, xpages

I am creating a JAVA method that returns an array of Strings, my method looks like this:

```
public String[] getReaders(String linkKey){
     ...
     String[] rtn  = {thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSOriginator")[0] , thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSReadDraftName")};
     return rtn;
}
```

Now the field WFSOriginator is a single value field so I can just get the first value in the getItemValue, however, WFSReadDraftName may be null, a single value or have multiple names in it. I get the error that can't convert the vector to string. So do I have to iterate through the values in WFSReadDraftName and store them in an array first?

Also, is there an easy way to make the array. I could iterate through the list and put them into a hashMap to ensure uniqueness, but that seems a bit of overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniqueness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `List`s:

```
List<String> rtn = new ArrayList<>();
rtn.add(thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSOriginator").get(0));

Vector<String> vector = thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSReadDraftName");

if (vector != null)
    rtn.addAll(vector);

return rtn.toArray(new String[rtn.size()]);
```

Comment: Pretty Close but I get an error on the Line:
String[] array = thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSReadDraftName"));
that it can't convert Vector to String[]. I tried thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSReadDraftName").toArray() but it doesn't like that either.

Comment: @BillF I thought that method returned an array. See the update.

Comment: That does it Vectors, Arrays and Lists can get confusing. I have it working perfectly now!

Comment: There are a whole host of Java Lists, Sets and Maps, some of which can ensure uniqueness. Look at the link from my blog post http://www.intec.co.uk/mapping-java-collections/. Also, bear in mind that a lot of XPages elements can take Java objects other than arrays and they're much easier to handle in code instead of arrays. I'm not sure what the end result is for the String array, but it may be easier than using arrays. Vector has an addAll() method, if you want to set a field value. Or OpenNTF Domino API replaceItemValue method will autoconvert from any Java collection to a Vector for you.

Comment: If you know WSFOriginator only has a single value then I would think you should use thisDoc.getItemValueString("WFSOriginator").  That's kinda what that method is for I believe.  Also this timely post might be interesting to you:  http://edm00se.github.io/DevBlog/xpages/consistent-multivalue-formatting/

Comment: @David - that is correct I should have used the next line of code which was a field that is MV, as in String[] array = thisDoc.getItemValue("WFSReadDraftName")); Should have paid more attention to what I copied.

Comment: @David - the whole thing of vectors, arrays, list etc can be ratherr confusing especially when you need to get from one type to another. In my starting case I thought the obvious String[] as the return would work, and probably could, and I still don't entirely understand -- return rtn.toArray(new String[rtn.size()]);
But gradually getting there with this JAVA hill.

Comment: @BillF `rtn.toArray(new String[rtn.size()])` just puts the elements of the `rtn` list into an array (which we pass as an argument). Also, note that it's *Java* as opposed to *JAVA*.

Comment: If you're looking for the correct URL from @DavidLeedy above, it's: https://edm00se.io/xpages/consistent-multivalue-formatting/

Answer (score 0):

Bill,
If you've not seen it already this post:  http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2012/06/multi-value-fields-and-beans-in-xpages.html  Has good information on Java Beans and multi Value fields.

As info here is some code PIECES I'm currently using in my beans for working with multi-value.  Note though that I'm using the OpenNTF API which makes things a little easier.

the multi-value field that I'm working with is called "categoryAdmins".

Again - the blog post might be of more interest since you're not using the API currently.

good Luck.
Dave

```
private List<String>            categoryAdmins;

this.categoryAdmins = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
     * Get the Multi-Value Field Category Admins
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Object getCategoryAdmins() {

        if (null ==  this.categoryAdmins) {
            this.categoryAdmins = new ArrayList<String>();
        } 

        return this.categoryAdmins;

    }

/**
     * Translate the Category Admins to a Vector for saving back to Multi-Value
     * Field
     * 
     * @param inputMulti
     */
    public void setCategoryAdmins(Object inputMulti) {
        this.categoryAdmins = UtilStrings.getVectorizedStrings(inputMulti);
    }


// Load from document - Note Using OpenNTF API
    this.categoryAdmins = lookupDoc.getItemValue("categoryAdmins", ArrayList.class);

// Save back to document
lookupDoc.replaceItemValue("categoryAdmins", this.categoryAdmins);
```

Comment: I wish I could use the Domino API, but because I can not control the environment that my application will be installed in and there are Admins that will not install anything that is not IBM Certified. So I don't think that I can insist on my clients installing the API, and don't see an easy way around that. I have to be careful with the Ext Lib that it will work with the basic IBM Ext Lib.

Comment: Right and that makes perfect sense.  That's why I linked to that blog post.  I was using that to deal with multi-values before switching over to the API